# How to implement C++ raw string literals in VIsual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11

As you may already know, new string literals in C++ 11 can be expressed in a very flexible way.

`R"<delim>...<delim>";` - in this code the `<delim>` can be pretty much everything and also no escape characters are needed. Any kind of parentheses can be used to delimit the end of string, Raw string literals are especially useful when defining regular expressions:

`R"(I love those who yearn for the impossible. (Von Goethe, "Faust"))";`

Blocks of text can be simply defined using equal occurrences of same characters:

`R";***************************(
  ; TINY BASIC FOR INTEL 8080

  ;       VERSION 2.0

  ;     BY LI-CHEN WANG

  ; MODIFIED AND TRANSLATED

  ;    TO INTEL MNEMONICS

  ;     BY ROGER RAUSKOLB

  ;     10 OCTOBER, 1976

  ;       @COPYLEFT

  ;  ALL WRONGS RESERVED      )
  ;***************************";`

More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#New_string_literals) (Wikipedia).

I want to implement it with C++ processor, here is what I have. Now double quotation marks are not supported, and I need to compete it like C++ 11. Can anyone help me?

```
#define STR(a) #a
#define R(var, re)  static char var##_[] = STR(re);\
const char * var = ( var##_[ sizeof(var##_) - 2] = '\0',  (var##_ + 1) );
```

You can use it like this:

```
R(re, "\w\d");//It's OK, no warnings.
```

The code is not friendly to use. So I want the feature like C++ 11 raw string literals.

PS: I'm using Visual C++ 2010, the new feature is not supported, I must implement it by myself.

Comment: I highly doubt you can do better without some sort of built-in language support.

Comment: why not? what's your recommendations?

Comment: Something like this `#define RAW(s) std::string(#s)` works for most examples but it seems to strip the newline, which I assume you want.

Comment: @Triumphant: hypothetically, if this *could* be implemented purely as a preprocessor hack, why would the standards committee have bothered to make it a core language feature? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of a side note: The example you posted is not a raw string literal as in the C++11 standard. The marker must be no more than 16 characters, and your ending with ') ;' does not match the beginning mark. Spaces are not allowed. As another side, this works fine with visual studio 2012+ the CTP ( http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36204698243/setupcpp11-msvs )

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string x=R";************(; TINY BASIC FOR INTEL 8080
    ; VERSION 2.0
    ; 10 OCTOBER, 1976
    ; @COPYLEFT
    ; ALL WRONGS RESERVED );************";
    std::cout << x <<std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not compile for me in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: the CTP is required. Have a look at my link.